# Reverse an array upto a given position only

Tags: arrays, c#-4.0, reverse

How to reverse an array upto specified position in c#

Comment: `Array.Reverse` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z78xtwts

Answer (score 0):

static int[] ReverseArray(int[] arr, int i) {

```
    int[] arrnew = new int[8];
    int k = i;
    for (int j = 0; j < k / 2; j++)
    {
        int temp = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[k - j - 1];
        arr[k - j - 1] = temp;
    }
    return arr;
}
```